# How to coloring rows for different groups of data

Tags: jasper-reports

I pass to *JasperReports*'s report an ordered (ASC) list of object.

Each record has a code that can be repeated.

For example:

```
1 row 123 (123 is the code)
2 row 123
3 row 567
4 row 567
5 row 567
6 row 908
7 row 908
```

I need that the rows with the same code have the same color. When the code changes (from 2 row to 3, for example) also the color changes. Again, from 5 to 6 row.. etc.. The alternation of just two color is fine.

How can I do that with *JasperReports*?

Comment: Can you post your code please, so we can help you!

Comment: @YoucefLaidani Which code do you mean?

Comment: @DavideFruci You can use variable & conditional style. Or you can use conditional style with condition on Group - it is a better solution. You can add Group on code field

Comment: @AlexK, ok but how? I google it but I don't find any example about that!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your task using ***Group*** and ***Conditional Styles***. Both features are widely used in *JasperReports*.

### How it works?

We need conditional style to change styles of text in row based on **code** (in your case *code={123, 567, 908}*). As we can see from the name of this feature - we need condtion! In case of your task we can take advantages of Grouping in *JasperReports*. The ideal candidate for Group's expression is **code** from the task. After creating the Group by **code** we can use the "Group Number" variable for make condition for our style.

In case having the group ***codeGroup*** we can create variable like this:

```
<variable name="groupNo" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="codeGroup" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

- we are just incrementing the simple counter for our Group. The value for the all records with code **123** will be ***1***, for **567** - ***2*** and so on.

### The working sample

#### Datasource

The *csv* datasource will be great for our sample. I'll use this one:

```
num,code
1,123
2,123
3,567
4,567
5,567
6,908
7,908
```

I'll skip the first row with columns names in datasource adapter settings.

#### Report's template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="styles_conditional_for_groups" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5edd462e-9135-43d5-a3d2-552c8663900a">
    <style name="commonStyle">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{groupNo} % 2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFAFAF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="num" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="code" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="groupNo" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="codeGroup" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="codeGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="277" height="20" uuid="a40aec12-cff7-4a0e-a608-90ccc02b42df"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="277" y="0" width="277" height="20" uuid="199f1eac-9ebd-47ff-a83f-a0c873531235"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Code]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="commonStyle" x="0" y="0" width="277" height="20" uuid="b21d1d5f-6a26-461d-97e4-95e01ff8ae34"/>
                <box leftPadding="20">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{num}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="commonStyle" x="277" y="0" width="277" height="20" uuid="4ffbd686-63bf-4d75-84d5-02379da445fe"/>
                <box leftPadding="20">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I used several simple features like borders and alignments in this template for pretty view.

### The result

I like *iReport* designer and I made screenshot with help of preview mode.

[image: The preview in iReport]

### Notes

As you can see, every step is very simple. Don't forget to sort data to get the valid group's data.

---

More info:

- about [**Groups**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)
- about [**Conditional Styles**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#conditionalstyles)

Comment: in your reponse in the "How it works?" part please tell me what do `CDATA[1]` and `CDATA[0]` represent?